# Join 3 tables and select only the top average for each category

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

So I have three tables I need to join and then select the average number of stars for a given month, we will say June and then for each category select all the businesses.  So far I have:

```
SELECT  B1.Name, B2.Category, AVG(R1.Stars) as Average
FROM Business B1
INNER JOIN Reviews R1
ON B1.ID=R1.BusinessID 
INNER JOIN BusinessCategories B2
ON B2.BusinessID=R1.BusinessID
WHERE R1.Date >= convert(datetime,'01-6-2011') AND R1.Date <= convert(datetime,'30-6-   2011')
GROUP BY Name, Category
ORDER BY Category, AVG(R1.Stars) DESC
```

Which gets me each businesses average but I don't know how to select the top for each of these categories.

**Update:**  Adding sample output what I have currently and what I'm looking for:

Here is what I get now:

```
Victoria Secrets    Accessories 5
Francesca's Collections Accessories 5
Saint 22    Accessories 4
Loehmann's Inc  Accessories 3
Arcadia Ice Arena   Active Life 5
Arizona Sunrays Gymnastics & Dance Center   Active Life 5
Blissful Yoga Studio    Active Life 5
Corner Archery  Active Life 5
Imagination Avenue  Active Life 5
Jump Street Active Life 5
Life Time Fitness   Active Life 5
```

But what I want is:

```
Victoria Secrets    Accessories 5
Arcadia Ice Arena   Active Life 5
Video Paradise  Adult   5
```

Or I guess even better would be that if there is a tie, like a bunch of the active life category we get back all the top businesses for that category.

Comment: Can you provide the output you are getting now? And the desired output?

Comment: Sorry I spaced on that important fact.  I have included sample of what I am getting and what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Category, T1.Average
FROM
(SELECT  B1.Name, B2.Category, AVG(R1.Stars) as Average
FROM Business B1
INNER JOIN Reviews R1
ON B1.ID=R1.BusinessID 
INNER JOIN BusinessCategories B2
ON B2.BusinessID=R1.BusinessID
WHERE R1.Date >= convert(datetime,'01-6-2011') AND R1.Date <= convert(datetime,'30-6-   2011')
GROUP BY Name, Category
ORDER BY Category, AVG(R1.Stars) DESC) T1

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  B1.Name, B2.Category, AVG(R1.Stars) as Average
FROM Business B1
INNER JOIN Reviews R1
ON B1.ID=R1.BusinessID 
INNER JOIN BusinessCategories B2
ON B2.BusinessID=R1.BusinessID
WHERE R1.Date >= convert(datetime,'01-6-2011') AND R1.Date <= convert(datetime,'30-6-   2011')
GROUP BY Name, Category
ORDER BY Category, AVG(R1.Stars) DESC) T2 on T2.Average> T1.Average AND T1.Category= T2.Category
WHERE T2.Name IS NULL
```

**OR**

```
SELECT Name,Category,Average FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By Category ORDER BY AVG(R1.Stars) DESC) as RN, B1.Name, B2.Category, AVG(R1.Stars) as Average
FROM Business B1
INNER JOIN Reviews R1
ON B1.ID=R1.BusinessID 
INNER JOIN BusinessCategories B2
ON B2.BusinessID=R1.BusinessID
WHERE R1.Date >= convert(datetime,'01-6-2011') AND R1.Date <= convert(datetime,'30-6-   2011')
GROUP BY Name, Category
ORDER BY Category, AVG(R1.Stars) DESC
) T
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible: Try the first query in my edited answer. That seems nasty, but your table structure is not available to make better query.

Answer (score 0):

Use max(R1.Stars) instead of avg(R1.Stars)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT FIRST(Name) AS BName, Category, MAX(Average) AS TopAverage
FROM (
    SELECT  B1.Name, B2.Category, AVG(R1.Stars) as Average
    FROM Business B1
    INNER JOIN Reviews R1
    ON B1.ID=R1.BusinessID 
    INNER JOIN BusinessCategories B2
    ON B2.BusinessID=R1.BusinessID
    WHERE R1.Date >= convert(datetime,'01-6-2011') AND R1.Date <= convert(datetime,'30-6-   2011')
    GROUP BY Name, Category
) q
GROUP BY Category
ORDER BY Category, TopAverage DESC
```